# How can I enable invisible files with "Transmit" FTP client?

Tags: macos, software, 3rd-party, ftp

How can I enable invisible files with "Transmit" FTP client ?

It asks me to show them only if I override one of them. I actually would like to always see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Show Invisible Files